# Switch connectionstring by visiting subfolder EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Rewritten my previous question without confusing code samples.

This is what i'm trying to achieve (or have done so far)

1. I created a webapplication to be viewed at www.myschool.com
2. I want to use subdomains so different schools can login to their personal school database (no central db)
3. I have 2 subfolders in my webapplication "school1" and "school2"
4. When a school visits www.myschool.com/school1 it should load the webapplication in the root folder by using the connectionstring provided in web.config from it's subfolder (school1 has web.config, school2 has web.config)
5. When www.myschool.com is entered (no subdomain) it should show the database "school1" as default

The databases are sqlserver databases and I use EF with .edmx file "SchoolModel" wich contains the entity model for the individual school databases, those have equal tabbles, fields, ... .

What currently happens:

1. When visiting www.myschool.com it shows the application with database from default school1
2. When entering www.myschool.com/school1 it just shows HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden because that folder only contains a web.config with another connectionstring for that specific school.

In the end a school (school1 or school2) should be able to enter school1.myschool.com or school2.myschool.com to view the webapplication loaded with content of it's personal database.

Using central database to serve both is not an option in this particular application.

Thanks for helping me setting this up

Comment: When your web application starts up the connection strings are verified and tested. I suspect this means you won't be able to get the connection strings to alter after startup. You would though be able to have an EDMX for each necessary database and then you can switch accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate the `SchoolModel_Entity` with the correct connection string in the first place, eg: `var myContext = new SchoolModel_Entity("connectionstring");`

Comment: @BenRobinson The code above is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I can't find another way to automatically switch connectionstring by subdomain. Can you provide me with an example to get me started? I have no idea where to start, maybe global.asax?

Comment: @neuzehie, You example doesn't make much sense, i.e. instantiate the the DbContext with one connection string then change it to another. Just use the correct one in the first place.

Comment: @BenRobinson What I'm trying to achieve: I have a website hosted at www.myschool.com but I want that site to be used by 2 different schools. If school1 would enter "school1.myschool.com" they should view the website at myschool.com with their specific database, if school2 enters "school2.myschool.com" they would see other data from their personal database. (should I edit my question and explain it otherwhise?). Can I create empty folders on my server "school1" and add a copy of web.config there with it's unique connectionstring?